# How to setup json library in c++? (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, json

I have downloaded the nlohmann library in a zip format and I need to understand where to unzip it. I know it's a header only library. Do I unzip it under

`/usr/include`
or
`/usr/include/c++/8`

So the directory will look like:

`/usr/include/nholmann/include`
or
`/usr/include/c++/8/nholmann/include`

Comment: Here's a [header-only library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) (requires c++14).

Comment: Can I know how to setup? Can you give me the step? Thanks!

Comment: There are no steps, just `#include "json.hpp"`. That's what `header only` means.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information...

Comment: For C++/WinRT, you can use UWP's `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, and `JsonValue` interfaces without adding outside files or external headers. Right now there's a bug for Visual Studio project templates for C++ WinRT apps where you need to add `/Zc:twoPhase-` to the Properties->C++->Commandline section, but other than this it is pretty hassle-free. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there are many JSON libraries out there. I would recommend you to use this one (requries C++11):

https://github.com/nlohmann/json

It is header only so no installation is requried. It has MIT Licences which is good even for commercial use. Also it is widely used so if you have any trouble it will be easy to find some resources on internet. On stackoverflow look for tag [nlohmann-json](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nlohmann-json/info)

To use it you would have to add 
`#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`
For more info check [github integration](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#integration)

Comment: Can I know how to setup? Can you give me the step? Thanks!

Comment: It is all there on github page. Just look. Bu basically the setup is just adding proper include to project

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information..

Comment: Also can the person who downvote tell me what is wrong with my answer?